# iterating over table rows and executing setInterval per row does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, datatables

I'm trying update a value of a cell from Offline to Online (and vice-versa) inside my `DataTable` by accessing a web service.

```
var $myTable = $("#my-table").dataTable();
var $myTableRows = $myTable.fnGetNodes();

for(var i=0; i<$myTableRows.length; i++) {
    var $currentRowCount = i;
    var $interval = $($myTableRows[i]).find("td:eq(9)").html();
    var $timeout = $($myTableRows[i]).find("td:eq(10)").html();
    var $dataINeedToPass = $($myTableRows[i]).find("td span:eq(4)").html();
    setInterval(function() { updateStuffOnTheTable($interval, $timeout, $dataINeedToPass, i); }, 4000);
}

function updateStuffOnTheTable(interval, timeout, dataINeedToPass, row) {
    var $stuff = "Offline";
    var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
            url : "https://localhost:8443/cxf/mywebservice/" + dataINeedToPass,
            type : "GET",
            dataType : 'text',
            timeout: 2000
        }).done(function(data) {
            $stuff = "Online";
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            $stuff = "Offline";
        })
        .always(function(data) {
            $myTable.fnUpdate($stuff, row, 2);
        })
}
```

The problem is, the AJAX request only executes once instead of every 4000ms. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably working as intented, except that the browser will keep obtaining the requested data from cache, because you keep querying the same URL.

To workaround this, its common practice to add a dummy variable to the querystring with the time of the query or a random number, it will change the URL forcing the browser to retrieve it from the server again.

So basically you can declare `var now = new Date();` on your function updateStuffOnTheTable and then mount your URL like this:

```
"https://localhost:8443/cxf/mywebservice/" + dataINeedToPass + '?now=' + now.getTime()
```

You may also try to solve this by using POST requests, sinse AJAX POST requests are not cached.